# Event logging shows different values. How?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events

Working with react component that looks like this:

```
  <TreeView
                  data={processTreeViewItems(arrayItemsDropdown9, {
                    check: check
                  })}
                  checkboxes={true}
                  onCheckChange={onCheckChange}
                />
```

it's a kendo react treeview component:

[image: First one is checked]

So, on onCheckChange, I log the **event** and after it I log **event.target.props.data**. If I inspect the event and go into target-props-data, I see this (As you can see above, the First one is checked/has checked:true)

[image: first one has checked:true, second one doesn't]

BUT, if i log **event.target.props.data** I see the previous state where both of them were checked:

[image]

How is this possible?